# temporarily keep old wifi router running while configuring new one?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

**I don't intend to set up a home network with two routers which is what a lot of the existing posts here and elsewhere cover.**

I just want to have the convenience of having the old connection up while I am setting up the new router with DD-WRT.  Mostly to be sure to be able to look up DD-WRT config info if needed.

The new router needs to have connectivity for the duration so that I can download manufacturer and DD-WRT firmware (though I could do that using the old router from the computer).

What I was thinking:

- hook up new router's internet/cable port to one of the old router's wired ports
- start up new router and give it a temporary SSID network name and password (my current password should work).
- connect computer to new router's SSID via wifi @ 192.168.1.1 (to admin it) and to old computer via wired ethernet.  old wifi is still around, as a different SSID

(at this point, my computer can admin the router on the new SSID and fall back to wired access on the old router if I turn off its wifi)

- carry out the router config
- turn off old router and plug new router's internet cable into my ISP access connection.
- reconfigure new router with my previous SSID and password.

Any gotchas I should look out for or suggestions?  Obviously, I could just remove my old router from the get-go, but why fly blind if you don't have to?

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine. The only problems you could get are if there is a DHCP server conflict, with two DHCP servers running on the same network.

The way I'd normally do it (as DD-WRT takes it's firmware upgrades manually from your computer anyway) is, assuming you have WiFi and ethernet:

1. Take note of your current IP address and default gateway on your old network
2. Disconnect your WiFi from the old network
3. Connect an ethernet cable between your computer and the new router
4. Make sure your new router is on a different subnet (change its local IP address if required) to your old router, so as to remove conflicts whilst you're configuring both
5. Reconnect to WiFi

That way, you are removing any potential clashing between having two DHCP servers running on one network. Of course, you can disable the DHCP server on your new router also when you connect it.

It's a lot easier to administrate a router whilst on an ethernet connection, as any changes to the WiFi set up will often disconnect you, so I'd recommend doing it that way around.

Comment: Ah, txs for the dhcp reminder.  I thought I was going to avoid hassles with the wifis using different ssids but I had forgotten the dhcp aspect on wired.